# If $p = a^2 + b^2$, prove that $(ab^{-1})^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ be a prime, where $p = a^2 + b^2$. Show that $(ab^{-1})^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$

I'm having trouble with this question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your title should be $b^{-1}$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Every non-zero element has an inverse $\pmod p$.

Comment: it is clear that $a^2=-b^2$ in the prime field $\mathbb F_p$

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, but $1\equiv -4\bmod 5$ looks more familiar than $\frac{1}{4}\equiv -1 \bmod 5$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Familiar is always good.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply both sides by $b^2$ and you get $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod p$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: It should be “Start from $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$”. I see no place where to multiply by $b^2$.

Comment: @egreg The necessary steps go in both directions.

Comment: Starting from the thesis doesn't seem the best way to prove it.

Comment: @egreg It's a hint, but a hint that's goes so far towards the answer that I think it's worth posting as an answer.  Giving such kinds of answers is typical around here I see it all the time.